# Jenkins is not installing some node dependencies

Tags: node.js, jenkins, npm, npm-install

I'm running a nodejs application's build on jenkins. I run node as shell script step, because I have some limitations in terms of the plugins I can install in this jenkins instance.

This is what the `npm install` step looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash +x
source ~/.bashrc
cd $WORKSPACE/ && \
nvm use 7.8.0 && node --version && npm install
```

The problem I have is, when `npm install` finishes, it doesn't install everything. If I ssh into the box where jenkins is installed and run npm install inside that project's workspace, with the same user jenkins uses, it works ok. Any ideas?

**EDIT**

I just realized the **dependencies** that it's not installing are **devDependencies**

Answer (score 2):

The problem was I had the node env set to production, and of course, it wouldn't get the devDependencies...